# cannot load a shared library at runtime

Tags: c, ld, dlopen, shared-libraries

foo.h

```
#ifndef foo_h__
#define foo_h__ 
extern void foo(void); 
#endif
```

foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h" 
void foo(void)
{
    puts("Hello, I'm a shared library");
}
```

compiled using

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c foo.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

dyna.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h> 
typedef void (*foo)(void);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    void* lib;
    foo df;
    printf("argc: %d\n",argc);
    if(argc < 2)
        return printf("USAGE: %s lib-file\n", argv[0]);

    lib = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_NOW);
    if(lib == NULL)
        return printf("ERROR: Cannot load library\n");

    df = dlsym(lib, "foo");
    if(df)
    {
    df();
    }
    else
        printf("ERROR: Invalid library\n");
    dlclose(lib);
}
```

compiled using:

```
gcc -rdynamic -o dyna dyna.c -ldl
```

run:

```
./dyna libfoo.so
argc: 2
ERROR: Cannot load library
```

I do not understand where am I going wrong...

Comment: You should use `dlerror()` for error reporting of `dlopen` or of `dlsym`

Comment: yes, the man page says that! read it now, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read carefully the [dlopen(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) man page.

```
 If filename contains a slash ("/"), then it is interpreted as a
 (relative or absolute) pathname.  Otherwise, the dynamic linker 
 searches for the library as follows:
```

So you should run

```
 ./dyna ./libfoo.so
```

or

```
 ./dyna $PWD/libfoo.so
```

or you could set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to contain `.` (which is not recommended)

P.S. don't forget to use `dlerror()` for error reporting, and remember that `dlopen` is probably not re-entrant (so if you have a multi-threaded application, serialize the calls to `dlopen` and `dlsym` with some mutex).

Comment: thank you :) that worked perfectly!!! I'll remember to scan the man pages next time!!

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple actually, the loader doesn't look in the current directory.  Try:

```
./dyna ./libfoo.so
       ^^^
```

Everything else looks good.

Comment: Thank you :) That worked, though Basile Starynkevitch's answer is more informative.